# Datanucleus MongoDB Exception persisting data

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus, nosql

i'm working on input some data into Mongodb through Datanucleus.

this is a part of the data that i use.

```
STD_YM|BLOCK_CD|BZ_SCLS_CD|BZ_LOBZ_SCLS_NM|M10_APV_CNT|M20_APV_CNT|M30_APV_CNT|M40_APV_CNT|M50_APV_CNT|M60_APV_CNT|W10_APV_CNT|W20_APV_CNT|W30_APV_CNT|W40_APV_CNT|W50_APV_CNT|W60_APV_CNT|M10_SALE_AMT|M20_SALE_AMT|M30_SALE_AMT|M40_SALE_AMT|M50_SALE_AMT|M60_SALE_AMT|W10_SALE_AMT|W20_SALE_AMT|W30_SALE_AMT|W40_SALE_AMT|W50_SALE_AMT|W60_SALE_AMT
201303|11220600300011000001|307009|������|0|8205|31102|23541|11972|6869|0|2863|12005|8553|5875|2022|0|464743912.58|2068701224.98|1802065918.66|933525067.07|502156752.49|0|156241028.98|759822379.88|604698640.27|412770581.02|148236607.2
201303|11230640300021000001|307001|ȭ��ǰ|0|1488|2308|1336|1437|168|28|9737|4614|2423|1503|249|0|23547325.77|43333197.38|18429589.09|25254914.78|3146259.88|436685.97|134084889.79|71525545.96|43535225.85|26759523.59|6475514.59
201303|31130140204001000001|410004|��ö��|0|0|40|100|40|40|0|0|0|60|20|0|0|0|1109420.55|2357518.72|554710.28|1030176.23|0|0|0|931120.83|158488.65|0
201303|11240580100101000004|414002|����Ŀ��|0|304|1843|494|171|38|0|646|855|323|114|38|0|8101568.28|51174650.98|12994670.42|4424084.16|1244333.5|0|11491898.46|22623897.36|6870635.31|1506600.73|1244333.5
201303|11230640200081000005|204001|����|0|1311|1221|374|154|33|0|176|55|44|0|33|0|64411996.88|66785690.31|23915179.14|8912210.94|2127286.51|0|11812038.37|2194464|2071305.31|0|2239248.98
201303|11230640200081000002|409009|��������|0|228|654|175|99|33|0|143|286|66|22|0|0|2440404.98|9782980.19|2435064.92|1025290.5|336423.45|0|1836978.8|3903579.97|1132091.6|411184.22|0
```

and here are two pojo class that i made.

POJO 1. SALE_AGE

```
package org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial;

import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Serialized;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

/**
 * Created by Sungjin on 2016-03-15.
 */
@PersistenceCapable

public class SALE_AGE {
    @PrimaryKey
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String Date;
    private String District_code;
    private String Business_code;
    private String Business_name;
    private double M10_APV_CNT;
    private double M20_APV_CNT;
    private double M30_APV_CNT;
    private double M40_APV_CNT;
    private double M50_APV_CNT;
    private double M60_APV_CNT;
    private double W10_APV_CNT;
    private double W20_APV_CNT;
    private double W30_APV_CNT;
    private double W40_APV_CNT;
    private double W50_APV_CNT;
    private double W60_APV_CNT;
    private double M10_SALE_AMT;
    private double M20_SALE_AMT;
    private double M30_SALE_AMT;
    private double M40_SALE_AMT;
    private double M50_SALE_AMT;
    private double M60_SALE_AMT;
    private double W10_SALE_AMT;
    private double W20_SALE_AMT;
    private double W30_SALE_AMT;
    private double W40_SALE_AMT;
    private double W50_SALE_AMT;
    private double W60_SALE_AMT;

    public String getDate(){return Date;}
    public void setDate(String STD){this.Date=STD;}

    public String getDistrict_code(){return District_code;}
    public void setDistrict_code(String block){this.District_code=block;}

    public String getBusiness_code(){return Business_code;}
    public void setBusiness_code(String CD){this.Business_code=CD;}

    public String getBusiness_name(){return Business_name;}
    public void setBusiness_name(String NM){this.Business_name=NM;}

    public double getM10_APV_CNT(){return M10_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM10_APV_CNT(double m10){this.M10_APV_CNT=m10;}

    public double getM20_APV_CNT(){return M20_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM20_APV_CNT(double m20){this.M20_APV_CNT=m20;}

    public double getM30_APV_CNT(){return M30_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM30_APV_CNT(double m30){this.M30_APV_CNT=m30;}

    public double getM40_APV_CNT(){return M40_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM40_APV_CNT(double m40){this.M40_APV_CNT=m40;}

    public double getM50_APV_CNT(){return M50_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM50_APV_CNT(double m50){this.M50_APV_CNT=m50;}

    public double getM60_APV_CNT(){return M60_APV_CNT;}
    public void setM60_APV_CNT(double m60){this.M60_APV_CNT=m60;}

    public double getW10_APV_CNT(){return W10_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW10_APV_CNT(double w10){this.W10_APV_CNT=w10;}

    public double getW20_APV_CNT(){return W20_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW20_APV_CNT(double w20){this.W20_APV_CNT=w20;}

    public double getW30_APV_CNT(){return W30_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW30_APV_CNT(double w30){this.W30_APV_CNT=w30;}

    public double getW40_APV_CNT(){return W40_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW40_APV_CNT(double w40){this.W40_APV_CNT=w40;}

    public double getW50_APV_CNT(){return W50_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW50_APV_CNT(double w50){this.W50_APV_CNT=w50;}

    public double getW60_APV_CNT(){return W60_APV_CNT;}
    public void setW60_APV_CNT(double w60){this.W60_APV_CNT=w60;}

    public double getM10_SALE_AMT(){return M10_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM10_SALE_AMT(double m10){this.M10_SALE_AMT=m10;}

    public double getM20_SALE_AMT(){return M20_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM20_SALE_AMT(double m20){this.M20_SALE_AMT=m20;}

    public double getM30_SALE_AMT(){return M30_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM30_SALE_AMT(double m30){this.M30_SALE_AMT=m30;}

    public double getM40_SALE_AMT(){return M40_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM40_SALE_AMT(double m40){this.M40_SALE_AMT=m40;}

    public double getM50_SALE_AMT(){return M50_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM50_SALE_AMT(double m50){this.M50_SALE_AMT=m50;}

    public double getM60_SALE_AMT(){return M60_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setM60_SALE_AMT(double m60){this.M60_SALE_AMT=m60;}

    public double getW10_SALE_AMT(){return W10_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW10_SALE_AMT(double w10){this.W10_SALE_AMT=w10;}

    public double getW20_SALE_AMT(){return W20_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW20_SALE_AMT(double w20){this.W20_SALE_AMT=w20;}

    public double getW30_SALE_AMT(){return W30_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW30_SALE_AMT(double w30){this.W30_SALE_AMT=w30;}

    public double getW40_SALE_AMT(){return W40_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW40_SALE_AMT(double w40){this.W40_SALE_AMT=w40;}

    public double getW50_SALE_AMT(){return W50_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW50_SALE_AMT(double w50){this.W50_SALE_AMT=w50;}

    public double getW60_SALE_AMT(){return W60_SALE_AMT;}
    public void setW60_SALE_AMT(double w60){this.W60_SALE_AMT=w60;}
}
```

POJO 2. SALE_TIME

```
package org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial;

import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

/**
 * Created by Sungjin on 2016-03-15.
 */
@PersistenceCapable
public class SALE_TIME {
    @PrimaryKey
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String Date;
    private String District_code;
    private String Business_code;
    private String Business_name;
    private double APV_CNT_00_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_01_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_02_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_03_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_04_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_05_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_06_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_07_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_08_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_09_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_10_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_11_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_12_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_13_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_14_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_15_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_16_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_17_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_18_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_19_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_20_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_21_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_22_AMT;
    private double APV_CNT_23_AMT;
    private double SALE_00_AMT;
    private double SALE_01_AMT;
    private double SALE_02_AMT;
    private double SALE_03_AMT;
    private double SALE_04_AMT;
    private double SALE_05_AMT;
    private double SALE_06_AMT;
    private double SALE_07_AMT;
    private double SALE_08_AMT;
    private double SALE_09_AMT;
    private double SALE_10_AMT;
    private double SALE_11_AMT;
    private double SALE_12_AMT;
    private double SALE_13_AMT;
    private double SALE_14_AMT;
    private double SALE_15_AMT;
    private double SALE_16_AMT;
    private double SALE_17_AMT;
    private double SALE_18_AMT;
    private double SALE_19_AMT;
    private double SALE_20_AMT;
    private double SALE_21_AMT;
    private double SALE_22_AMT;
    private double SALE_23_AMT;

    public String getDate(){return Date;}
    public void setDate(String std){this.Date = std;}

    public String getDistrict_code(){return District_code;}
    public void setDistrict_code(String block){this.District_code = block;}

    public String getBusiness_code(){return Business_code;}
    public void setBusiness_code(String cd){this.Business_code =cd;}

    public String getBusiness_name(){return Business_name;}
    public void setBusiness_name(String nm){this.Business_name = nm;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_00_AMT(){return APV_CNT_00_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_00_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_00_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_01_AMT(){return APV_CNT_01_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_01_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_01_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_02_AMT(){return APV_CNT_02_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_02_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_02_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_03_AMT(){return APV_CNT_03_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_03_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_03_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_04_AMT(){return APV_CNT_04_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_04_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_04_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_05_AMT(){return APV_CNT_05_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_05_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_05_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_06_AMT(){return APV_CNT_06_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_06_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_06_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_07_AMT(){return APV_CNT_07_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_07_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_07_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_08_AMT(){return APV_CNT_08_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_08_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_08_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_09_AMT(){return APV_CNT_09_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_09_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_09_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_10_AMT(){return APV_CNT_10_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_10_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_10_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_11_AMT(){return APV_CNT_11_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_11_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_11_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_12_AMT(){return APV_CNT_12_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_12_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_12_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_13_AMT(){return APV_CNT_13_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_13_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_13_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_14_AMT(){return APV_CNT_14_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_14_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_14_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_15_AMT(){return APV_CNT_15_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_15_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_15_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_16_AMT(){return APV_CNT_16_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_16_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_16_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_17_AMT(){return APV_CNT_17_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_17_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_17_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_18_AMT(){return APV_CNT_18_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_18_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_18_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_19_AMT(){return APV_CNT_19_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_19_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_19_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_20_AMT(){return APV_CNT_20_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_20_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_20_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_21_AMT(){return APV_CNT_21_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_21_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_21_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_22_AMT(){return APV_CNT_22_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_22_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_22_AMT = apv;}

    public double getAPV_CNT_23_AMT(){return APV_CNT_23_AMT;}
    public void setAPV_CNT_23_AMT(double apv){this.APV_CNT_23_AMT = apv;}

    public double getSALE_00_AMT(){return SALE_00_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_00_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_00_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_01_AMT(){return SALE_01_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_01_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_01_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_02_AMT(){return SALE_02_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_02_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_02_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_03_AMT(){return SALE_03_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_03_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_03_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_04_AMT(){return SALE_04_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_04_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_04_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_05_AMT(){return SALE_05_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_05_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_05_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_06_AMT(){return SALE_06_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_06_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_06_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_07_AMT(){return SALE_07_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_07_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_07_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_08_AMT(){return SALE_08_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_08_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_08_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_09_AMT(){return SALE_09_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_09_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_09_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_10_AMT(){return SALE_10_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_10_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_10_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_11_AMT(){return SALE_11_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_11_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_11_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_12_AMT(){return SALE_12_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_12_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_12_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_13_AMT(){return SALE_13_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_13_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_13_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_14_AMT(){return SALE_14_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_14_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_14_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_15_AMT(){return SALE_15_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_15_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_15_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_16_AMT(){return SALE_16_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_16_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_16_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_17_AMT(){return SALE_17_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_17_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_17_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_18_AMT(){return SALE_18_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_18_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_18_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_19_AMT(){return SALE_19_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_19_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_19_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_20_AMT(){return SALE_20_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_20_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_20_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_21_AMT(){return SALE_21_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_21_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_21_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_22_AMT(){return SALE_22_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_22_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_22_AMT = sale;}

    public double getSALE_23_AMT(){return SALE_23_AMT;}
    public void setSALE_23_AMT(double sale){this.SALE_23_AMT = sale;}
}
```

And here is a Main method.

```
package org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial;

import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.SourceTree;
import org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.NOT_EMBEDDED.NOT_EMBEDDED_SALE_AGE;
import org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.NOT_EMBEDDED.NOT_EMBEDDED_SALE_TIME;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;
import javax.jdo.Extent;
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.Transaction;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Tutorial");
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("Age Data.txt"), "euc-kr"));
        String[] arr = {"201303", "201304", "201305", "201306", "201307", "201308", "201309", "201310", "201311", "201312", "201401", "201402"};
        String url = "src/main/resources/SALE_AGES/DMS_SALES_EST_AGE_";
        long total_time = 0;

        try {
            for (String s : arr) {
                String filepath = url + s + ".txt";
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filepath)), "euc-kr"));
                String line;
                int i = 0;
                int count = 0;
                tx.begin();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (i != 0) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        SALE_AGE data = SaleAgeData(line);
                        System.out.println("datain");
                        pm.makePersistent(data);//error occurs
                        System.out.println("persisted");
                        tx.commit();
                        System.out.println("commited");
                        pm.deletePersistent(data);
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception persisting data : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }


    }

    static SALE_AGE SaleAgeData(String line) throws Exception {
        String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
        SALE_AGE tmp = new SALE_AGE();
        tmp.setDate((fields[0]));
        tmp.setDistrict_code(fields[1]);
        tmp.setBusiness_code(fields[2]);
        tmp.setBusiness_name(fields[3]);

        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[4]));
        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[5]));
        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[6]));
        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[7]));
        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[8]));
        tmp.setM10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[9]));

        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[10]));
        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[11]));
        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[12]));
        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[13]));
        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[14]));
        tmp.setW10_APV_CNT(Double.parseDouble(fields[15]));

        tmp.setM10_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[16]));
        tmp.setM20_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[17]));
        tmp.setM30_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[18]));
        tmp.setM40_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[19]));
        tmp.setM50_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[20]));
        tmp.setM60_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[21]));

        tmp.setW10_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[22]));
        tmp.setW20_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[23]));
        tmp.setW30_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[24]));
        tmp.setW40_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[25]));
        tmp.setW50_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[26]));
        tmp.setW60_SALE_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[27]));


        return tmp;
    }

    static SALE_TIME SaleTimeData(String line) throws Exception {
        String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
        SALE_TIME tmp = new SALE_TIME();

        tmp.setDate((fields[0]));
        tmp.setDistrict_code(fields[1]);
        tmp.setBusiness_code(fields[2]);
        tmp.setBusiness_name(fields[3]);

        tmp.setAPV_CNT_00_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[4]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_01_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[5]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_02_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[6]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_03_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[7]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_04_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[8]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_05_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[9]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_06_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[10]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_07_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[11]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_08_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[12]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_09_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[13]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_10_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[14]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_11_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[15]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_12_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[16]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_13_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[17]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_14_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[18]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_15_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[19]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_16_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[20]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_17_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[21]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_18_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[22]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_19_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[23]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_20_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[24]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_21_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[25]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_22_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[26]));
        tmp.setAPV_CNT_23_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[27]));

        tmp.setSALE_00_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[28]));
        tmp.setSALE_01_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[29]));
        tmp.setSALE_02_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[30]));
        tmp.setSALE_03_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[31]));
        tmp.setSALE_04_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[32]));
        tmp.setSALE_05_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[33]));
        tmp.setSALE_06_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[34]));
        tmp.setSALE_07_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[35]));
        tmp.setSALE_08_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[36]));
        tmp.setSALE_09_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[37]));
        tmp.setSALE_10_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[38]));
        tmp.setSALE_11_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[39]));
        tmp.setSALE_12_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[40]));
        tmp.setSALE_13_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[41]));
        tmp.setSALE_14_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[42]));
        tmp.setSALE_15_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[43]));
        tmp.setSALE_16_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[44]));
        tmp.setSALE_17_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[45]));
        tmp.setSALE_18_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[46]));
        tmp.setSALE_19_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[47]));
        tmp.setSALE_20_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[48]));
        tmp.setSALE_21_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[49]));
        tmp.setSALE_22_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[50]));
        tmp.setSALE_23_AMT(Double.parseDouble(fields[51]));

        return tmp;

    }
}
```

when i run it, the first line

```
201303|11220600300011000001|307009|������|0|8205|31102|23541|11972|6869|0|2863|12005|8553|5875|2022|0|464743912.58|2068701224.98|1802065918.66|933525067.07|502156752.49|0|156241028.98|759822379.88|604698640.27|412770581.02|148236607.2
```

inserted well but after first input,

Exception persisting data : Exception inserting object for StateManager[pc=org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.SALE_AGE@4b9a6c67, lifecycle=P_NEW]

Exception occured.

i dont know why the second line is not persisted. maybe, did i done something wrong with persistence manager??

can anybody help why i cant persist all the data?

Comment: Exception occurred, yet you don't bother posting the exception. The real exception. The one in the log.

Comment: sorry i forgot again. i'll add real exception in the log right away

Comment: i know the problem and fixed. the problem was duplicated primary key, so i made id field and put object id in it to prevent duplicate primary keys. Thanks for your advice :-)

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).